# Tkinter window only showing after the process

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a script to download file. I tinker it using tkinter. My idea is to show a new window when download button is clicked and show the progress of the download in it. I create new window but problem is it will not show the window until the download is complete..

```
b2 = Button(text = "Image Download",font=("Raleway", 10),command =  lambda:     download('Image','.jpg'), width=20)
b2.pack()
```

when this execute the download() executes in download():

```
window = Toplevel(root) 
window.geometry('600x350+305+220')
window.wm_title(TYPE + ' Download')
```

this is for creating new window. But it only shows when the download() finish executes

What should i do? Help me

Comment: This code isn't enough for us. You need to provide us with a minimal reproduction so that we have something to copy/paste into our editors to run and see your actual problem for ourselves. I suspect your problem is that you're running `download()` on the main thread, which blocks Tkinter from being able to update. You need to run it on a background thread instead.

Comment: Jerin, edit the scope and post the code, i think in many issues possible but i can help without the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have not shown the code that downloads the data but it is clearly using a synchronous method. All windowing systems operate by processing events. When a window is created and event is generated to map it onto the screen and another to get it to draw on screen. If you do not allow the thread to process events then apparently nothing happens until you stop being busy.

To work around this you either need to use an asynchronous method of downloading the data or you can use a synchronous method but you must do this on another thread. The UI thread (the one you create your windows on) MUST keep processing events. This basically means never do anything that will take a long time. The Tkinter `after()` method is a common scheme to break up a long job into lots of small pieces that are posted as events to keep things working. In this case its probably simplest to create a worker thread to do the download and post progress updates to the UI thread regularly.

Comment: import threading
p1 = threading.Thread(target=download, args=(arguments))
p1.start()     u meant this thread .... am not familiar with it..